# Retrieved data from firebase but get a null pointer exception when trying to use the retrieved data

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, substring

I have images displayed in a recyclerview that were retrieved from a Firebase database. I am trying to implement an alphabet index so that when I click on a letter, the name of the image gets retrieved. I then apply a substring to get the first character of the name, use the equals() to check if the character is equal to the letter clicked and remove the item from the recycler view if it is not equal. The problem is when I apply the substring a null pointer exception is produced. I know that I am successfully retrieving the name of the image as I am able to use a Toast to display it on the screen. I don't know what is causing the null pointer exception when I try to get the substring. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code from main activity - the problem is in the updateLogoDisplay():

```
public class AddBrandPage extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    //declare variables
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView alpharecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager alphaLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter alphaAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    private Button btn_skip;
    private Button btn_save;
    private CheckBox checkbox;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String t;

    List<LogoItems> brandLogo = new ArrayList<>();
    //HashMap<String, String> saveBrands = new HashMap<>();
    List<LogoItems> removedBrandLogo = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> selectionList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AlphaItems> alphaList = new LinkedList<>();


     String [] alphabets = {"All","A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
            "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_brand_page);

        //initialize variables
        btn_skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/brands");
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/users");
        // checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        //calls to load data to arraylists
        //alpha = getResources().getStringArray(alphabets);

        loadAlpha();
        loadLogoImgData();


        //set the listener for the buttons click event
        btn_skip.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private void loadAlpha() {

        for (String alpha: alphabets) {
            alphaList.add(new AlphaItems(alpha));

        }
        startAlphaRecyclerView();

    }

    public void loadLogoImgData() {

        brandLogo.clear();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot brandSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    LogoItems value = brandSnapshot.getValue(LogoItems.class);
                    brandLogo.add(value);
                }
                startLogoRecyclerView();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == btn_skip) {
            //if skip button clicked close current window and go to user main page
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserMainPage.class));

        }
        if (view == btn_save) {
            //selector.addAll(logoadapter.selector);
            saveData();
        }

    }


    public void startLogoRecyclerView() {
        // set the main recyclerview view for the logo in the layout
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // set the main layoutManager of the recyclerview
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // set the recycler view adapter
        adapter = new LogoAdapter(brandLogo, getBaseContext(), AddBrandPage.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void startAlphaRecyclerView() {
        // set the main recyclerview view for the logo in the layout
        alpharecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.alpharecyclerView);
        alpharecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // set the main layoutManager of the recyclerview
        alphaLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        alpharecyclerView.setLayoutManager(alphaLayoutManager);

        // set the recycler view adapter
        alphaAdapter = new AlphaAdapter(alphaList, getBaseContext(), AddBrandPage.this);
        alpharecyclerView.setAdapter(alphaAdapter);

    }



    public List<String> prepareSelection(View v, int position) {

        checkbox = (CheckBox) v;

        //check if user selected checkbox and add or remove from list
        //if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
        selectionList.add(brandLogo.get(position).getName());

        //} else {
        // selectionList.remove(brandLogo.get(position).getLogo());

        //}
        return selectionList;
    }



    public void updateLogoDisplay(String letter) {

        if (!(letter.equals("All"))) {
            //Iterator<LogoItems> iter = brandLogo.iterator();

            for (Iterator<LogoItems> iter = brandLogo.iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            //while (iter.hasNext()) {
                LogoItems r = iter.next();
                String c = r.getName();
                String t = c.substring(0,1);
                if (c != null){
                    if (letter.equals(t)) {


                    //brandLogo.remove(r);
                    removedBrandLogo.add(r);
                    iter.remove();

                }
                }else {
                }
            }
            brandLogo.removeAll(removedBrandLogo);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


    public void saveData() {

        final FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        final DatabaseReference userRef;

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        DatabaseReference curUser = userRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        curUser.child("brands").setValue(selectionList);//save selected items to the database

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the recycler view adapter from which the updateLogoDisplay() gets called.

```
public class AlphaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder> {

    //declare variables
    List<AlphaItems> alphaList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;
    private Context context;


    //the constructor
    public AlphaAdapter (List<AlphaItems> alphaList, Context context, AddBrandPage addBrandPage){
        this.alphaList = alphaList;
        this.context = context;
        this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;

    }


    @Override
    public AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.alpha_items, parent, false);
        AlphaViewHolder alphaViewHolder = new AlphaViewHolder(view,addBrandPage);
        return alphaViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AlphaAdapter.AlphaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txt_alpha.setText(alphaList.get(position).getLetter());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alphaList.size();
    }

    public class AlphaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        //declare variables
        private TextView txt_alpha;
        private AddBrandPage addBrandPage;


        //the constructor
        public AlphaViewHolder (View itemView, AddBrandPage addBrandPage){
            super(itemView);
            this.addBrandPage = addBrandPage;

            //initialize variables
            txt_alpha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_alpha);

            //set click listener
            txt_alpha.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            String letter = alphaList.get(position).toString();
            addBrandPage.updateLogoDisplay(letter);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
06-15 15:42:10.306 30577-30577/com.test.test D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-15 15:42:10.307 30577-30577/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.test.test, PID: 30577
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.test.test.AddBrandPage.updateLogoDisplay(AddBrandPage.java:253)
                                                                     at com.test.test.AlphaAdapter$AlphaViewHolder.onClick(AlphaAdapter.java:78)
                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-15 15:46:57.570 30577-30626/com.test.test W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: Inside updateLogoDisplay your curly brackets are off; maybe this is the issue so please fix the layout

Comment: I've double checked, the curly brackets are not off. I don't think the program would be able to run to produce the null exception if that were the case. @Aenadon

Comment: Hmm okay. Can you please try the following: Put a breakpoint on `String t = ...` and then see if c has actually got a value, then use IntelliJ's "Evaluate Expression" to evaluate `r.getName();` in the debugger

Comment: I've done as instructed. When I put the debugger on String t = ... and run the program, it shows a value for c.  When I use the Evaluate Expression to evaluate r.getName() it produces a result. The result is consistent with the value given for c on the String t = ... line. I have tried changing the String t = ... to String t = s.charAt(0) and I still get the null pointer exception. @Aenadon

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. When the iteration reaches the end, the variable c becomes null. This is what is producing the null pointer exception. To avoid the null error I added if (c != null) before the String t = ... line.  @Aenadon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. When the iteration reaches the end, the variable c becomes null. This is what is producing the null pointer exception. To avoid the null error I added if (c != null) before the String t = ... line.